# (d3pie) несколько пирогов на одной странице

Tags: javascript

Использую библиотеку [d3pie](http://d3pie.org) для построения двух лиаграмм в виде пирога на одной странице. 
Вызываю примерно вот так:

```
var pie1  = new d3pie("pieCanvas1", {
...
});

var pie2  = new d3pie("pieCanvas2", {
...
});
```

При этом пироги начинают конфликтовать между собой классами.

Внутри d3pie.js есть такая штука:

```
// used to uniquely generate IDs and classes, ensuring no conflict between multiple pies on the same page
var _uniqueIDCounter = 0;
```

Она, по идее должна решать проблему, но видимо она не задействуется т.к. я каждый раз делаю new. Может я не правильно запускаю? Не очень силен в яваскрипте.

PS. Пироги запускаются в виде виджетов и они не знают друг о друге. Их может быть 2 или 10, не известно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. При инициализации пишем:

```
var pie1  = new d3pie("pieCanvas1", {
    misc: {
        cssPrefix: 'pie1' //можно что угодно, но здесь индекс пирога = 1
    }
});
```

И классы будут идти с этим конкретным префиксом, не конфликтуя друг с другом.